# Springboot api calls are not multithreaded in IntelliJ debug mode

Tags: spring-boot, multithreading, intellij-idea

I have a springboot app in which I have defined API Controller method like this

```
@GetMapping("/getUsers")
public ResponseEntity<String> getUsers(){
// step 1
// step 2
// step 3
}
```

I have started app in debug mode in IntelliJ, and have set breakpoint at step 1 in code. 
I am calling my API from postman. 
I make first request and it hits the breakpoint. 
Then I make another request but it doesn't hit breakpoint.
Only when I execute 1st request completely and it returns then only my breakpoint for 2nd request is hit.
So the execution of requests seems to be happening sequentially.
Any pointers on what is going wrong here?

thanks

Comment: What are the breakpoint properties? Do you suspend all threads?

Comment: They are default. How can I change breakpoint properties?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#breakpoint-properties

Comment: Try changing the suspend mode to Thread: https://i.imgur.com/RGBWioe.png.

Answer (score 0):

See the [breakpoint properties dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#breakpoint-properties) and change the suspend mode from All to **Thread**:

[image: thread]